# Service Fabrice Local Cluster Manager Node setup error

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to run service fabric local cluster manager but it is giving following error : **Failed to setup local cluster**. 
I have Microsoft Azure service fabric SDK 3.2.187 installed locally.

Steps I followed is -

Install Visual studio 2017 - version - **4.7.03056**. While installing I selected Azure development workload from VS installer.

After VS installation, I installed Service Fabric SDK from Web Platform Installer.

After this right click on Service fabric local cluster manager -> Setup local cluster -> 1 Node.

When I do this, I am getting **There were errors while setting up the local cluster. Retrying..**

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you try do "Reset Local Cluster" and the "Setup Local Cluster"?

Comment: Error I mentioned in post I getting when I do Setup Local cluster. I tried reset local cluster but still same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar issues many times when I tried to install SF on local machine.
Try the following steps:

First of all, check if you have IIS enabled on your PC from Windows Features. If it is disabled, enable IIS and related features.

If this not helped, do the following:

**Uninstall:**

1. Remove the installed Service Fabric SDK, Runtime and VS tools
2. Delete installation folder under C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric
3. Delete folder from registry: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Service Fabric
4. Reboot PC

**Install:**

If you already installed Microsoft Web PI, run the program and **install the Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK again the following way**:

1. Check if IIS is selected from the configuration of installation
2. Check if the prerequisite C++ package is installed during the process (Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) ).

Then

3. Install Service Fabric tools using the Visual Studio Installer
4. Run the command `Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force -Scope CurrentUser` from a  command line as admin

Hope this helps.

Comment: Cheers mate! Removing registry key made difference!

Comment: @Dev Cool :)  did it resolve the problem? Are you able to use the local cluster now?

Comment: Yes. It resolved. I am able to use local cluster now

Comment: @Dev can you then mark this as an answer? So other would know this checklist works.

Answer (score 0):

Delete Fabric*.dll under C:\Windows\System32 makes it work for me.

It seems new SF would not insert these binaries into System32 folder, while old version uninstall program would not delete them. So it cause version corruption in running new version.